# Public function when called from another contract throws error "The called function should be payable if you send value"?

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, erc-20, payable

This is the contract I am calling from:

```
contract MultiTransfer {
    function multiTransfer(Marcelo token, address _addresses, uint256 amount) public {
        
            token.transfer(_addresses, amount);
        
    }
}
```

This the contract where the transfer function is:

```
contract Marcelo is ERC20Interface, Owned {
    using SafeMath for uint;

    string public symbol;
    string public  name;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint public _totalSupply;

    mapping(address => uint) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function Marcelo() public {
        symbol = "MRL";
        name = "Marcelo";
        decimals = 18;
        _totalSupply = 250000000 * 10**uint(decimals);
        balances[owner] = _totalSupply;
        Transfer(address(0), owner, _totalSupply);
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Total supply
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint) {
        return _totalSupply  - balances[address(0)];
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get the token balance for account `tokenOwner`
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Transfer the balance from token owner's account to `to` account
    // - Owner's account must have sufficient balance to transfer
    // - 0 value transfers are allowed
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(tokens);
        balances[to] = balances[to].add(tokens);
        Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }
....
...
```

I am using remix to compile and deploy locally to test. When I pass arguments to `transfer` function in contract `marcelo` it works as expected but when I do so in contract  `MultiTransfer` for function `multiTransfer` it gives me an error and reverts back. `transact to MultiTransfer.multiTransfer errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.`

Can someone please help me understand what am I doing wrong? There have been similar questions that have been asked but they have not been much of a use to me.

Comment: Given that you have at hand a `MultiTransfer` instance named `x` and a `Marcelo` instance named `y`, what do you get when you call `y.balanceOf(xAddress)`?

Comment: it gives 0 since I did not transfer any tokens to the contract itself. So one should transfer tokens to the contract `MultiTransfer` and then call the function?. It does work now! I think I understand it now (correct me if I am wrong). When calling function `multiTransfer` the callee/sender is the contract `MultiTransfer` but it has no tokens to transfer. I think earlier I was calling it thinking  "I" am calling the `multiTransfer` function.

Comment: You are not wrong.